# How can I launch portable firefox app as a separate application?

Tags: scripts, firefox, launcher, sh, plank

I like to compartmentalize my internet browsing. I use one browser for work related stuff, one browser personal banking and bills, and another browser for general social related stuff like online forums and youtube.

Until now, I've simply used a combination of the Pre-installed Firefox, Chromium, and Waterfox. However, I much prefer to use the latest Firefox for all three. I am not interested in using different profiles for the one browser, as I like to have all three open at the same time.

**EDIT: See Bruni's answer below. Three separate profiles is in fact the way to go, using the -no-remote function.**

I recently used [this](https://www.airaghi.net/en/2017/03/22/install-mozilla-firefox-portable-on-linux) script by Davide Airaghi to create 2 portable versions of firefox.  I moved the two portable firefox folders to ~/firefox-work and ~/firefox-social. The pre-installed version is what I use for banking and other personal stuff.

I have all three running at the same  time, and they work fine, however in my Plank launcher, they all show up under the same icon. Is there any way I can launch each of these portable firefox apps and the pre-installed app, and have them be shown in Plank as three separate applications?

Comment: You can use workspace; enable the option inside *System parameter* -> *Appearance* -> *Behavior* and tick the option named *Enable workspace*

Answer (score 2):

> I am not interested in using different profiles for the one browser, as I like to have all three open at the same time.

There is no reason not to use profiles for the above reason. If you invoke the profiles with -no-remote. E.g. I have a profile called Bruni. If I invoke it with

```
firefox -P Bruni -no-remote
```

I can also invoke another profile. You can use .desktop files to make your life easier.

> Never use -no-remote to start the "default" profile (the one that is
>   set to open without asking when you launch Firefox). That's because
>   when you launch Firefox, for example, by clicking a link in your mail
>   program, you will get a "Firefox is already running but is not
>   responding" message if the default profile is already in use. The
>   solution is to always start the default profile normally and launch
>   all others with -no-remote. Then it will work.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile

Comment: Thank You. I've done exactly this. - I made 3 new Firefox Profiles (Personal, Work and Social). Then I edited the main menu (I use Ubuntu-mate, so it's right click on the brisk menu). In the Internet category, I added 3 news items with commands; firefox -P Personal -no-remote %u, firefox -P Work -no-remote %u, firefox -P Social -no-remote %u, and even gave each of them a different colored firefox icon. I then dragged each of the three launchers from the Brisk menu into the Plank Dock, and now all three act as separate programs. Works like a charm. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To launch the portable Firefox app as a separate application, simply double-click on the executable file of the portable Firefox installation. This allows you to run Firefox independently without affecting your system's installed version.